# Context Provider is not a Route component error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm getting this error when I wrap some of my routes in a Context Provider tag. I basically need to send the logged user context to each of these routes for them to use or modify. The value sent in the provider is this:

```
const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState(null)
const value = useMemo(() => {{ loggedUser, setLoggedUser }}, [loggedUser, setLoggedUser])
```

And here is the code:

```
return (
  <>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={ <MainPage /> } />
      <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginMenu/>} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterMenu/>} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard tasks={tasks} />} />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </Routes>
  </>
)
```

Comment: Only `<Route>` can be a child of `<Route>`

Answer (score 4):

Only `Route` component can be a child of a `Route` component. Abstract the `UserContext.Provider` component into a layout route.

Example:

```
import { Routes, Route, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const UserContextProvider = () => (
  <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
    <Outlet />
  </UserContext.Provider>
);

...

<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<MainPage />} />
  <Route element={<UserContextProvider />}>
    <Route path="/login" element={<LoginMenu />} />
    <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterMenu />} />
    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard tasks={tasks} />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Or wrap the entire `Routes` in the `UserContext.Provider` component.

Example:

```
return (
  <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={ <MainPage /> } />
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginMenu />} />
      <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterMenu />} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard tasks={tasks} />} />
    </Routes>
  </UserContext.Provider>
);
```